# Question about Cauchy-inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function and assume that there exist $M > 0$ and $r>0$ such that 
$$
|f(z)| \leq M |z|\ln |z|
$$
$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $z \geq r$. 
I need to prove that $f(z) = a+bz$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

My approach is the following: I use Cauchy's Inequalities:

$$|f^{(n)}(a)| \leq \frac{n!}{r^n} \max \{ |f(z)| : |z-a|=r \}$$

With this I find that:
$$|f^{2}(0)| \leq \frac{n!}{r^n} \max \{ |f(z)| : |z|=r \} \leq \frac{2}{r^2}M r\ln r =\frac{2}{r}M \ln r$$

I need to show that this is zero, but I don't see how. 
I know that this question is similar to [Using Cauchy's Inequality to prove a function's second derivative is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346602/using-cauchys-inequality-to-prove-a-functions-second-derivative-is-zero)
but I don't think of it as a duplicate, since there are other assumptions.

Comment: Let $r\to \infty$. You know the estimate holds for all $r$. Ditto for the higher derivatives $f^{(k)}(0)$.

Comment: But does the estimate hold for all $r$? Then the assumption should be: $\forall r>0$ there exists $M >0$ such that...

Comment: Ah, sorry. Use a circle of radius $R \geqslant r$ and let $R\to \infty$.

Comment: Okay I understand that, but then we have that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\geq 2$, but does that imply that $f^{(2)}(z) = 0$?

Comment: Look at the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$. You know that since $f$ is entire, it converges to $f$ on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: But, you could also let it be enough with only considering the second derivative, if you use the Cauchy estimates in the form $$\lvert f''(z)\rvert \leqslant \frac{2MR\ln R}{(R/2)^2}$$ for $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant R/2$.

Comment: Ah great, we see that $f(z) = f(0) + f'(0)z + 0 + 0 + \ldots $, due to the Taylor series. Thank a lot!